# CSS coloring on certain placeholder texts, but not all

Tags: css

Let's say that I have two input fields and one of them in mandatory the other not.

They should function as standard placeholders, ***except*** the placeholder text of the mandatory field should be red, the other should be placeholder default and they should both look the same after some text us input.

How do I achieve that, using CSS?

Comment: Sorry, downvoters, I somehow was not aware of the `required` keyword, and was searching for "mandatory". I could delete this, to avoid more downvotes, but will leave it open to help others in future (and, no doubt, it will one day make its way to the top of Google search, attracting even more down-votes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably helped by using the :required pseudo selector, possibly combining with the ::placeholder pseudo selector.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required />
```

CSS:

```
input:required {
    // CSS
}

input:required::placeholder {
    // CSS
}
```

Comment: How to I style the input box with that?

Comment: `<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Your Name"/>`

Comment: Your question did not include HTML, and in line with that I accidently forgot to include certain parts in the CSS. I've put your HTML in the answer too.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe that I didn't know about the `required` keyword. They must have slipped that one in when I wasn't looking :-/